# Nokia Lumia 1020 Camera

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1020

I don't speak English, but I would try to do my best since I can't find a solution to my problem on other forums. This weekend I was using my Nokia Lumia with no problem, but suddenly the camera stopped working. Every time I try to open it, it just closes, no matter if I use the offical application or another one. I have a Nokia Lumia 1020, here are some specifications shown on the information:
Model: Nokia 909
Software: Windows Phone 8.1 Update
OS Version: 8.10.14176.243
I'm using the Preview for Developers.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Have u tried restarting, soft reset ? Also is there enough storage space ?

Comment: Lumia Camera app needs more time to open compared to the default camera app. And may be you have a small space of memory

Comment: Do hard reset... It will working.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you can try:

- Remove and reinstall the Nokia Camera app
- Check if you have enough free space (like Nisha said)
- Do a soft reset
- If that doesn't work, try a hard reset
- if that doesn't work and you don't necessarily need the Preview, use the Nokia Software Recovery Tool to revert to the latest stable version

Comment: I've tried soft reset and hard reset, and after reset obviously there's enough space then also, Camera is not opening.